# std::unordered_map: multithreading insertions?

Tags: c++, multithreading, dictionary, unordered

I have a bunch of data (a giant list of integers between 0 and ULLONG_MAX) and I want to extract all unique values. My approach is to create an unordered_map, using the integer list values as the keys and a throwaway bool for the map values. I iterate the list and insert throwaway values for each key. At the end I iterate the map to get all unique keys. Pretty straight forward.

However, my list is so large (100s of millions) that I'd like to multithread this process. I know a naive approach to threading won't work, because unordered_map insertions affect the underlying data structure and so it's not thread safe. And adding locks around each and every insertion will be slow and possibly negate any threading speedup.

However, presumably not every insertion changes the data structure (only ones that can't fit in the existing allocated buckets?). Is there a way to check if an unordered_map re-allocation would be required for a particular insertion, prior to inserting? That way I could only lock threads when the map is getting changed, instead of locking during every insert. Then, prior to each insertion, the threads merely check if a lock exists...rather than doing a full lock/unlock. Is that possible?

Comment: What's wrong with `unordered_set` ?

Comment: You might try building multiple containers and then merging them.

Comment: @Sid Hmm, didn't know that was a thing. I guess I still have the same question regarding it though...

Comment: None of the `std::unordered_map` methods are thread-safe. That's pretty much it. None of the C++ library containers are thread safe. The End. The short answer to your question is: no, it's not possible.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I didn't ask if the functions are thread safe. Please re-read the question.

Comment: I would start by using `unordered_set::reserve()` to see if multithreading is really called for.  Can you make it fast enough by using a single thread ?

Comment: @SidS Does reserve(n) guarantee no future re-allocations for n insertions?

Comment: @Tyson, that's the way I understand the docs.

Comment: I reread your question. My comment remains the same. The answer is no. The fundamental fact is that none of the C++ library's containers are thread-safe. You are not guaranteed thread-safety no matter what. No exceptions to the rule. There's no way around it. Insertions into a map, or any C++ library container, are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Well read it a third time then. My question is not whether or not stl containers are thread safe. My question is whether there are methods that can be used to make insertion locking more efficient. Wrapped containers can be *made* thread safe, so the fact that they aren't inherently thread safe is irrelevant.

Comment: If there were any methods like that, they would be at least partially thread safe. But they're not. They were not thread safe when I wrote my first two comments, and, I just checked, they're still not thread safe. Sorry, but you have to lock every insert.No exceptions. Unfortunately, there is no magic button you can push and open a thread-safe back-door into an unordered map, or any other C++ library container. No such magic button exists. Containers are not thread safe. They never were, maybe some day, but not now. End of story. Again. Sorry, but that's the answer you'll always get.

Comment: `reserve`ing space will not alleviate the issue.  Even if re-hashing isn't needed, multiple threads could try to insert into the same bucket at the same time, and that would be a problem.  I agree there isn't a way to do this with a single container without locking for each insertion.

Comment: @Miles, My suggestion was to use `unordered_set::reserve()` and a single thread of execution to determine whether multithreading is actually necessary.

Comment: Instead of inserting into a set (or map), I'd sort chunks in place, and use `std::unique` on the chunks. Then merge the chunks together, and use `std::unique` on the result. Most of this (especially the sorts) is trivial to do in parallel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental rule of parallelization break the job up, work on the pieces, and then combine the pieces.

Hashing/item lookup is the most expensive part of the whole shebang, so that's what we'll focus on parallelizing.

If you absolutely need the result as a hash table, I got some bad news for you: you'll have to write your own. That being said, let's begin.

First, let's solve the problem in serial. this is simple. The below function takes a vector and a callback. We're going to take the vector, convert it into an `unordered_set`, and give the `unordered_set` to the callback. Simple? Yes.

Now, because we're going to be doing this on a thread, we can't do it right away. Instead, we'll return a lambda that takes no arguments. When that lambda is invoked, that's when it'll create the `unordered_set` and give it to the callback. This way, we can give each lambda to it's own thread, and each thread will run the job by invoking the lambda.

```
template<class Vector, class Callback>
auto lazyGetUnique(Vector& vector, Callback callback) {
    using Iterator = decltype(vector.begin());
    auto begin = vector.begin();
    auto end = vector.end();
    using elem_t = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type;

    //We capture begin, end, and callback
    return [begin, end, callback]() {
        callback(std::unordered_set<elem_t>(begin, end));
    };
}
```

Now - what should this callback do? The answer is simple: the callback should assign the contents of the `unordered_set` to a vector. Why? Because we're gonna be merging the results, and it's a lot faster to merge vectors than it is to merge `unordered_set`.

Let's write a function to give us the callback:

```
template<class Vector>
auto assignTo(Vector& v) {
    return [&](auto&& contents) {
        v.assign(contents.begin(), contents.end());
    };
}
```

Suppose we want to get the unique elements of a vector, and assign them back to that vector. This is now really simple to do:

```
std::vector<int> v = /* stuff */;
auto new_thread = std::thread( lazyGetUnique(v, assignTo(v)) );
```

In this example, when `new_thread` finishes executing, `v` will contain only unique elements.

Let's look at the complete function to do everything.

```
template<class Iterator>
auto getUnique(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
    using elem_t = typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type;

    std::vector<elem_t> blocks[4];

    //Split things up into blocks based on the last 4 bits
    //Of the number. This allows us to guarantee that no two blocks
    //share numbers. 
    for(; begin != end; ++begin) {
        auto val = *begin; 
        blocks[val & 0x3].push_back(val); 
    }

    //Each thread will run their portion of the problem.
    //Once it's found all unique elements, it'll stick the result in the block used as input
    auto thread_0 = std::thread( lazyGetUnique(blocks[0], assignTo(blocks[0])) );
    auto thread_1 = std::thread( lazyGetUnique(blocks[1], assignTo(blocks[1])) );
    auto thread_2 = std::thread( lazyGetUnique(blocks[2], assignTo(blocks[2])) );

    //We are thread_3, so we can just invoke it directly
    lazyGetUnique(blocks[3], assignTo(blocks[3]))(); //Here, we invoke it immediately

    //Join the other threads
    thread_0.join();
    thread_1.join();
    thread_2.join(); 

    std::vector<elem_t> result;
    result.reserve(blocks[0].size() + blocks[1].size() + blocks[2].size() + blocks[3].size());

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        result.insert(result.end(), blocks[i].begin(), blocks[i].end());
    }

    return result;
}
```

This function breaks stuff up into 4 blocks, each of which are disjoint. It finds the unique elements in each of the 4 blocks, then combines the result. The output is a vector.

Comment: Thank you for the writeup! The best takeaway for me is the clever trick to split up values into threads based on the last bits of each number, which ensures no two threads will be doing uniqueness tests on the same values. With that filter in place, the rest becomes trivially easy. I'm marking this as the answer since it's a very workable solution. Obviously a worst-case exists where all numbers get filtered into the same thread, but my values are pretty evenly distributed so I don't think I'll run into that problem.